# How can I work simultaneously for more than one employer?

Tags: human-resources, contracts, contracting, law, employment-agreement

I am offered full time permanent contracts from three employers. Due to experience in the tasks of these jobs, I am confident I can fulfill all of them each day (by working around 12-14h per day). What would be the best approach to work on these three roles simultaneously?

It seems that permanent contracts specify that you need to work for 40h per week for each employer so it will be 3x40=120h per week which is impossible (given I won't work on weekends). The next solution I see, is to negotiate a day rate. Would that enable me to work simultaneously? Also, can I still have a permanent contract on a day rate?

By the way, there is no conflict of interest as they are not competitors and totally different projects.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? If you want to be a contractor be a contractor, If you want to have the benefits of being a 'permanent' employee then take a full-time job. You can't have both.

Comment: *t seems that permanent contracts specify that you need to work for 40h per week...*, no it's the fulltime part that requires 40 hours a week. If you really think you can do all three jobs in half the time they're asking for then that's what you should be proposing to these employers.

Comment: You are asking for the legality but don't want to disclose your country?

Comment: just FTR I don't really know what a "permanent contact" is or could mean in this context

Comment: @Fattie I had to look it up. It means the contract doesn't have an end date.

Comment: If you’re in the United States, keep in mind that many contracts for full time positions include a clause that forbids other employment (sometimes only other _full time_ employment). Note that IANAL and I have no idea if these clauses are legal or enforceable, but at-will employment probably means they could just terminate you anyways.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a straight up bad idea. Employers will expect you to be at their disposal during their work hours (assuming you'd be staff and not contractor). You'd also be setting yourself to over commit and under deliver. I'm certain it's a better idea to under commit and over deliver, for your long term reputation.

Most importantly, this will absolutely break your physical and mental health and you'll pay for it in time.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work for multiple companies at the same time and manage your own time (which you *will* have to do if you're doing 3 jobs at once) then you can't be an employee, you need to be a contractor or freelancer or something similar.

It will be a very rare full time position that is going to accept "I can't join the meeting, I'm working for another company at that time" from their employees.

You also cannot fulfill 3 full time jobs in 14 hours per day, since each full time job expects you to spend 8 hours on them. If you run out of work sooner, each company will expect you to ask/look for more work *for them*. Again, if you want to finish their work in less time and move on to your next job, you're not an employee, you're a contractor.

And finally... working 12-14 hours a day is going to be really bad for your health. I'd advise against it.

Comment: Hm. I could imagine it for certain types of jobs. Say the combination teacher (where you could do the correction works on the weekend), university teacher (where you could in some places do only the minimum required, not asking for homework, just reading from a book) and night deskman in a hotel (where your main task would be to wait until trouble happens, so you could do your corrections). But obviously, my example was just a theoretical one and not useful. And of course, working that much is bad.

Answer (score 0):

Employers will rarely agree to this so you will have to hide it from them. Hiding will be a problem due to things like overlapping meetings or a particularly busy day at one employer interfering with your work for another.

If you really want to do it you should not be an employee, but a contractor (I don't mean an employment contract here, but a business to business contract). Then you negotiate the terms of your work with the client. Simply ensure there's no clause in the contract that prevents you from having other clients. There are all sorts of contracts, some do it by the hour some by work delivered. If you bill for work delivered then the client couldn't care less about whether you work 10 hours a week or 100, so long as you get it done. If you make it hourly, then they will probably want some proof from you that the hours were actually worked and necessary - but they also may be less strict about how many hours it was and at what time.

In any case, there are obviously many clients out there as evidenced by how many contractors have multiple concurrent clients. So you can certainly find some that will accept it.